# How to position ScrollView after animation has stopped

Tags: android, android-widget, android-animation

I have a ScrollView that contains a LinearLayout, in the LinearLayout I have a view that I expand or collapse depending on a button being pushed.  This piece works just fine.

What I would like to do is re-position the ScrollView so that when the view is expanded it automatically re-positions the scroll view so that the expanded view is visible.  I would like to the view to reposition it self automatically so the user does not have to scroll.
Currently when the view is expanded everything get's pushed down and you have to scroll up to view the newly expanded content.  I tried repositioning after the animation has ended but that section of code never fires.  Below is my code.

```
public void animateExpandCollapse(View v) {

        View captionLayout = null;
        View parentLayout  = null;

        if(v.getId() == R.id.squareCal) {
            captionLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout3);
            parentLayout  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.squareLayout);
        } else if(v.getId() == R.id.circleCal) {
            captionLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout2);
            parentLayout  = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.circleLayout01);
        }


        if (!more) {
            dda = new DropDownAnim(captionLayout, 350, false);
            more=true;
        } else {
            dda = new DropDownAnim(captionLayout, 350, true);
            more=false;
        }
        dda.setDuration(350);
        parentLayout.startAnimation(dda);

        // Here, I want to position ScrollView to the bottom
        // After the animation has finished but this never fires.
        if(dda.hasEnded() ) {
            ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.calScroller);
            sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getBottom());
        }

        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching online I found the following solution.  I hope this helps someone.

```
dda.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.calScroller);
                sv.scrollTo(0, sv.getBottom());
            }
        });
```